# Networkx: How do I use bfs_tree(graph, source) when source is not an integer but an object?

Tags: python, networkx

I have defined a Vertex class to use its objects as nodes in the graph. Once I have constructed a graph, I am having problem calling the function bfs_tree(G, source) because I do not know how to give the source (which is not an integer but a vertex object).

Comment: Use the vertex object as the source?  Could you post example code of what you are trying?

Comment: is this vertex type hashable?